# Get data from other sheet according to the date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google spreadsheet with the following information:

[image]

The three cells highlighted with green, A1, A2 and A3 get content from sheets D1, D2 and D3 with *=Sheet3!D1* -function. Is it possible to update the content according to the date, so when it's Monday D1, D2 and D3 are shown, but on Tuesday, D4, D5 and D6 are shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in A1, you don't even have to use `Column C` in formula

> =OFFSET(D1,(WEEKDAY(today(),2)-1)*3,0,3,1)

[image]
if you want to use `Column C` then in A1 use

> =OFFSET(D1,MATCH(SWITCH(WEEKDAY(today(),2),1,$C$1,2,$C$4,3,$C$7,4,$C$10,5,$C$13,6,$C$16,7,$C$19),C1:C21,false)-1,0,3,1)

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thank you. I tried this but nothing shows on the cell A1 after I run it. There is no error, but nothing shows either..

Comment: I guess that's because, you don't have entries for `today` in column `C and D`

Comment: use `=OFFSET(D1,(WEEKDAY(today()+4,2)-1)*3,0,3,1)` , advance `today()+4` so it will be `Monday`